# Gatsby site - CSS in index.js doesn't load on first access

Tags: html, css, gatsby, responsive

i'm building my first gatsby site and i've run into a few css issues during deployment.

1. first off, when i load the [site](https://claudiahleung.github.io/gatsby-learnings), none of the css loads - but when i click on `latest promotions/hktaxi` (completed pages) and then `epayment services` (links back to index.js - same as homepage), the css loads. i initially thought this was a netlify issue, which is why i decided to deploy it to github pages too - but the page looks exactly the same on both platforms.
2. the page is responsive on web, but not on mobile. i've read solutions online that the meta tag for the viewport should be put in my html file - however, i don't have one. should i be creating a `html.js` file and inserting the meta tag there?

put the repo here for reproducibility: [github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings](https://github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lack of implementation but a few cents and a bunch of plausible causes:

1. It seems, according to the described behavior that you have some [hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/) issues. At the initial render point, none of your styles are being loaded or applied but when you move back and forwards (where rehydration occurs) it loads. This issue normally appears when you block that hydration by pointing directly to the DOM instead of React's virtual DOM (vDOM), for instance, when asking for `window` or `document` outside React's scope (without hooks).

   That said, this is an implementation issue, not a Netlify's or GitHub issue. This should (and must) happen when building your project locally, since, in the end, what Netlify's does is to build your project on their server and you should be able to reproduce it locally by `gatsby build && gatsby serve`. If locally things work as expected, you may start thinking in a Netlify issue (normally related with mismatching Node versions between environments).

   In your case, I'm pretty sure that your issue comes because you are using styled-components but you haven't read the [implementation details in Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/styled-components/) because you are missing the required plugins and details in your [`gatsby-config.js`](https://github.com/claudiahleung/gatsby-learnings/blob/main/blog/gatsby-config.js) such as:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-styled-components`],
   }
   ```
2. That's not true at all, you can [customize the HTML output](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) (because Gatsby allows you to do it) and manipulate it as you wish, adding the needed meta tags (which is not the solution to your issues). Simply run:

   ```
   cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
   ```

   Or manually copy the `default-html.js` from `.cache` folder to `/src` and rename it to `html.js`. If Gatsby, when compiling your project, finds that file under `/src` folder, will use it as a "template" for your compiled code. It will look like:

   ```
    import React from "react"
    import PropTypes from "prop-types"

    export default function HTML(props) {
      return (
        <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
          <head>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <meta
              name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
            />
            {props.headComponents}
          </head>
          <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
            {props.preBodyComponents}
            <div
              key={`body`}
              id="___gatsby"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
            />
            {props.postBodyComponents}
          </body>
        </html>
      )
    }

    HTML.propTypes = {
      htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
      headComponents: PropTypes.array,
      bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
      preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
      body: PropTypes.string,
      postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
    }
   ```

Outside the scope of the question. I would recommend ignoring the `.cache` and the `public` folders by adding them in the `.gitignore` file. They are autogenerated in each project compilation and it may lead you to some Git conflicts (unless you are the only contributor) but it's a good practice to don't push it to avoid noise in the repository.

Comment: thanks for the super detailed answer! i tried adding `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` to my config file, but my github pages site looks the same (e.g. janky index.js, css doesn't apply to mobile). index.js looks fine locally, and since netlify uses an optimised build (static html generated from `gatsby build`), i thought the problem happened there. i'll look more into hydration and give `html.js` a try for my mobile css

Comment: Check the implementation details of styled-components and check the Node versions to force GitHub pages to use the same version as you

Comment: actually - i think adding `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` worked for netlify (`index.js` now loads with all css styling + works on mobile), but didn't change anything on github pages. i'm not sure if this has anything to do with `gh-pages` and `main` branching, but i'm just glad netlify's working. thanks! :)